# is there a command line equivalent to git mergetool.--keepBackup global config

Tags: git, git-merge

Rather than having to set it up in the global config (which is an issue when it comes to developers sharing repositories) it'd be nice to do this automatically in our scripts, but `git mergetool --help` doesn't come up with anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass any configuration variable to `git` using [the `-c` option](http://git-scm.com/docs/git), e.g.:

```
git -c mergetool.keepBackup=false mergetool
```

should run `git mergetool` with `mergetool.keepBackup` set to `false`.

That's a bit long, so you may want to alias this, e.g.

```
alias.mt '!git -c mergetool.keepBackup=false mergetool'
alias.mtk '!git -c mergetool.keepBackup=true mergetool'
```

in the appropriate config file. Then `git mt` and `git mtk` should run `git mergetool` with `keepBackup` set to `false` and `true` respectively.

Comment: shouldn't that say =false to run it with it set to false?

Comment: It can be `true` or `false`, according to your needs. I wasn't clear on which one you wanted from your question.